# swift - Async tasks and pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple problem about check and set elements in array, but i wanna do it in Async tasks by multiple threads.

```
        override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          test()
        }


        let group_dis = DispatchGroup()
        var sum : [Int] = [Int] (repeating: 0, count: 10_000)
        func test() {
            self.group_dis.enter()
            f1(str: "thread 1", min: 0, max: 5000)

            self.group_dis.enter()
            f1(str: "thread 2", min: 100, max: 2699)

            self.group_dis.enter()
            f1(str: "thread 3", min: 5301, max: 9999)

            self.group_dis.wait()
            print(self.sum)
        }
        func f1(str: String, min : Int,  max : Int) {
            let q = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)
            q.async {
                print("running ..... \(str) ")
                for i in min..<max {
                    if (self.sum[i] < i) {
                        self.sum[i] = i
                    }
                }
                self.group_dis.leave()
            }
        }
```

Errors: 
TestDispatchQueueGroup(67208,0x700000c2c000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fb4e1022800: pointer being freed was not allocated
TestDispatchQueueGroup(67208,0x700000c2c000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I know it is crashed because conflicts in accessing memory cells on multiple threads.
But this is testing, with my large project, i am trying to find a solution to execute parallel tasks on same array.

Thanks for any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Swift arrays are not thread safe.  You need to ensure only one thread can update the array at a time.  One way of doing this is to dispatch all of your array updates synchronously on a dedicated serial dispatch queue

Comment: @Paulw11. I need to reduce the processing time so I want to parallel. Maybe can not.

Comment: You might want to look at Metal if you are looking for high-speed matrix manipulation.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for your suggestion, using Metal. I am trying.